# Create custom command to expand client detail template in Kendo UI Grid (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've got a nested grid within my grid, and it works perfectly, but the client doesn't like to use the arrow on the left and asked for a button to be added in order to show the child grid.

The example on the Kendo website shows how to automatically open the first row, I just want a way to expand the grid from a custom control in the same way that the left selector does it.

I've got the custom command working, and it executes the sample code, but I just need some help with the javascript required to make it work for the current row.

```
columns.Command(command => 
            { 
                command.Edit().Text("Edit").UpdateText("Save"); 
                command.Destroy().Text("Del");
                command.Custom("Manage Brands").Click("showBrandsForAgency");
```

And the js with the standard example of opening the first row:

```
function showBrandsForAgency(e) {
    this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
}
```

Please help by giving me the js required to expand the row clicked and not the first row?

*** EDIT ***
Modified the solution provided by Atanas Korchev in order to get it to work on only the button and not the whole row.

I'd prefer a solution that uses the function showBrandsForAgency instead of a custom funciton but this does the job:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#grid").on("click", "a", function (e) {
        var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
        var row = $(this).parent().parent();

        if (row.find(".k-icon").hasClass("k-minus")) {
            grid.collapseRow(row);
        } else {
            grid.expandRow(row);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
$("#grid").on("click", "tr", function(e) {
  var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");

  if ($(this).find(".k-icon").hasClass("k-minus")) {
    grid.collapseRow(this);
  } else {
    grid.expandRow(this);
  }
});
```

When using jQuery on the function context (available via the `this` keyword) is the DOM element which fired the event. In this case `this` is the clicked table row.

Here is a live demo: http://jsbin.com/emufax/1/edit

Comment: Thanks for the response. I had to modify it a bit, and this isn't the cleanest solution but it does the job.

Comment: Too complicated for the feature needed. look at my answer if need clean simple and efficient solution.

Answer (score -1):

Same results just Simpler, faster, and more efficient:

```
$("#grid").on("click", "tr", function () {
    $(this).find("td.k-hierarchy-cell .k-icon").click();
});
```